# Como eu revalidar um input sempre que um número for alterado?

Tags: javascript, input

> Olá,

O código abaixo verifica se o que foi digitado no input é maior ou igual a 10 e menor igual o valor disponível : 100.51. Se for verdadeiro o botão precisa ficar todo preto. 
O problema é que quando você digita R$90,00 por exemplo, a validação acaba sendo burlada. Mas se você der um ctrl + c e colar no input a validação é aplicada.

Existe alguma forma de sempre que algo for digitado dar um "Refresh" em javascript?

```js
function maskIt(w,e,m,r,a){    
    // Cancela se o evento for Backspace
    if (!e) var e = window.event
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;        
    // Variáveis da função
    var txt  = (!r) ? w.value.replace(/[^\d]+/gi,'') : w.value.replace(/[^\d]+/gi,'').reverse();
    var mask = (!r) ? m : m.reverse();
    var pos  = (a ) ? a.pos : "";
    var ret  = "";
    if(code == 9 || code == 8 || txt.length == mask.replace(/[^#]+/g,'').length) return false;
    // Loop na máscara para aplicar os caracteres
    for(var x=0,y=0, z=mask.length;x<z && y<txt.length;){
        if(mask.charAt(x)!='#'){
            ret += mask.charAt(x); x++;
        } else{
            ret += txt.charAt(y); y++; x++;
        }
    }   
    // Retorno da função
    ret = (!r) ? ret : ret.reverse()    
   if (w.value.match("-")){
        w.value = "-"+ret+pos;
    }else{
        w.value = ret+pos;
    }
}
// Novo método para o objeto 'String'
String.prototype.reverse = function(){
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};
//desabilita o botão no início
document.getElementById("botao").disabled = true;
//cria um event listener que escuta mudanças no input
document.getElementById("valordigitado").addEventListener("input", function(event){
  //busca conteúdo do input
    var valordispo = 100.51;
    var valorsolicitado = document.getElementById("valordigitado").value;
    var valorsolicitado = valorsolicitado.replace(",", ".");
    let valorsoli = Number(valorsolicitado);
    if (valorsoli >= 10 && valorsoli <= valordispo) { // O valor esta OK!
    //include "m3.html";
   // document.write(valorsoli);
    document.getElementById("botao").disabled = false;
    } else {
    document.getElementById("botao").disabled = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.button{background-color: black}
</style>
<input type="text" name="dinheiro" id="valordigitado" onkeyup="maskIt(this,event,'###.###.###,##',true,{pos:''})" class="line-animation" maxlength="7" step="0.01" autocomplete="off">
<button class="button" id="botao">Enviar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pra disparar algo sempre q algo é digitado no input, você pode usar o evento `keyup`

Comment: Um dos problemas que eu acabei de identificar, é após 6 dígitos aparece NAN no console.log, pois eu preciso de alguma forma deixar o replace até 999,99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utilize o evento "change":

```
document.getElementById("valordigitado").addEventListener('change',function(event){
  //código
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta! Deu certo!

Comment: Resta agora descobrir como deixar a variável valordispo correta no replace, pois não existe números com dois pontos, exemplo 1.1111.11 preciso limitar o replace para té 999.99

Comment: usa a função "parseFloat(numero)" para fazer isso,ele vai tranformar o número em decimal.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Nesta manhã cabei encontrando a solução para esta conversão:

Comment: var variavel = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2);

Comment: Oba !!!! ainda bem,estava suspeitando mesmo que a minha solução talvez não fosse a melhor.